# Facebook Share Button get Access Token

Tags: android, facebook, share

ı am developing an android app and I am using Facebook ShareButton for sharing content. It succesfully shares content. If user logged in with different provider, it requests facebook login. I am trying to link user accounts. If user logged in with email and password, then want to share some content on facebook. Click on the share button. Facebook wants  login. User logges in and content shared. The problem is I need the facebook access token to save provider. But I dont know how to do that. The share button code likes this;

```
            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("og:type", "restaurant.restaurant")
                    .putString("og:title", ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getCurrentRest().getName())
                    .putString("og:description", uc.formCheckinText())
                    .build();
            // Create an action
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("restaurant.visited")
                    .putObject("restaurant", object)
                    .build();
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName("restaurant")
                    .setAction(action)
                    .build();
            facebookCheckinButton.setShareContent(content);
```

Comment: You can't get an access token from the share dialog

Comment: But it does the login and validate the user.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the user can't share. But just because they share doesn't mean they want to grant your app any permissions

Comment: It does log the user in to Facebook. It does not log the user in to your app. Those are two different things.